# Configure LDAP for SUDO Support on Ubuntu Server 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, sudo

I'm running into some issues finishing my LDAP install. I used the following article to try the sudoers schema configured: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1421998

When I run

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,cn=config -W -f ~/sudoWork/cn\=sudo.ldif
```

I get the following output:

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

Here is my output from syslog:

```
Jul  5 06:24:11 dc1 slapd[802]: conn=4397 fd=22 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:51379 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Jul  5 06:24:11 dc1 slapd[802]: conn=4397 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,cn=config" method=128
Jul  5 06:24:11 dc1 slapd[802]: conn=4397 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=49 text=
Jul  5 06:24:11 dc1 slapd[802]: conn=4397 op=1 UNBIND
Jul  5 06:24:11 dc1 slapd[802]: conn=4397 fd=22 closed
```

For the record I am entering the correct password.  When I run other `ldap` commands with the password it works fine.

How should I go about debugging this? If there is any other info you need to help me debug this issue, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I miss read a step.  These lines need to be removed.
structuralObjectClass: olcSchemaConfig
entryUUID: 10dae0ea-0760-102d-80d3-f9366b7f7757
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20080826021140Z
entryCSN: 20080826021140.791425Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20080826021140Z